# Add RelatedProducts by Category

Tags: magento2, product-view, related-products, product-relations

I added related products by Catalog->products->select product->addrelated/crosssell..products. But I want add related products by category. How to do?

Answer (score 0):

This link worked for me.
use this extension
https://github.com/tabnaeem/related-products-by-category-magento2